# Function result from threading always delayed?

Tags: multithreading, function, delphi

I want to make an integer result from a thread. It's just a simple calculation. 
My problem, I can not have an "instant" result from it. I have execute more than once, then I got the correct result.

Here the unit form :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    mmo1: TMemo;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure CaclDone(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BeginCal(calA, calB: Integer);
    function StartCalc(const calA, calB: Integer): Int64;
  end;

var
  nOut: Int64;
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uCalculationThread;

procedure TForm1.BeginCal(calA: Integer; calB: Integer);
var
  P: TCalc;
begin
  nOut := 0;
  P := TCalc.Create;
  P.numa := calA;
  P.numb := calB;
  P.OnTerminate := CaclDone;
  P.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.CaclDone(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TCalc;
begin
  P := TCalc(Sender);
  nOut := P.iOut;
  mmo1.Lines.Add('on thread finished : ' + IntToStr(nOut)); // < here is instant result
end;

function TForm1.StartCalc(const calA, calB: Integer): Int64;
begin
  BeginCal(calA, calB);
  Result := nOut;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Int64;
begin
  i := StartCalc(10, 20);
  mmo1.Lines.Add('on function call : ' + IntToStr(i)); // first result always 0
end;

end.
```

And here is the threading unit

```
unit uCalculationThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TCalc = class(TThread)
  private
    fiOut: Int64;
    fnumA, fNumB: Integer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property numA: Integer read fnumA write fnumA;
    property numb: Integer read fNumB write fNumB;
    property iOut: Int64 read fiOut write fiOut;
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

constructor TCalc.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCalc.Execute;
begin
  fiOut := fnumA + fNumB;
end;

end.
```

What I need is a simple function to have the result from that thread.

Comment: what David is trying to say is that your code is not waiting for the thread to finish so you get the original value of i (which is 0). If you must wait on a calculation, then you need to use synchronization objects (Semaphore, Criticalsection, ...)

Comment: The result isn't known until the thread completes. Your use of OnTerminate is the right way to do this. You could also wait for the thread to complete. But that would render the thread pointless. As I read your question it sounds like that's what you want to do. In which case just remove the thread.

Comment: If you have a calculation Pipelines (ie calculation 2 depends on the results of calculation 1) then it is better to use the [TOmnithread library](https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html).

Comment: I suspect that your understanding of threading is deficient. You don't use threads to get "instant" results. Threads are just a means to allow multiple sections of code to execute at the same time (in parallel). The code doesn't run any faster in a thread. It's certainly not instant. In fact it is slower due to the overhead of starting a new thread. The benefit is the ability to do something else while the code runs. For instance like pumping a message queue to keep your UI responsive. My strong advice is to read more introductory texts on threading and parallel computing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you sir, actually, it was a heavy calculation, and disturb the form responsiveness. That's why I need to run it on a thread. How can i make a function `if DoAdd (2,2) <> 4 then` .... something like that in threading ?

Comment: I honestly suggest you read my comments again, and heed the advice given there.

Comment: If it's a calculation that you need an immediate result from, then it doesn't belong in a thread, whether it's a *heavy calculation* or not. Threads are designed to run in the background to do things without interfering with the UI or other processing. If it can't run in the background because you need the results now, then don't run it in a thread, and if you need it to run in a thread to keep the UI responsive then don't write your code in a way that needs results immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this method:

```
function TForm1.StartCalc(const calA, calB: Integer): Int64;
begin
  BeginCal(calA, calB);
  Result := nOut;
end;
```

It calls `BeginCal`, which creates a thread and starts its execution. The result of the thread is passed through the `OnTerminate` event which calls `CaclDone` and assigns the result to the `nOut` variable.

Since the `OnTerminate` event is executed in the main thread, this will happen **after** the execution of `StartCalc`. Hence, there will be no valid value for `StartCalc` to return.

---

> What I need is a simple function to have the result from that thread.

This means that the main thread will have to wait for the thread to finish its execution. That defeats the way the GUI is supposed to behave.

You already have a mechanism for getting the result in the `CaclDone` method.

---

The way to handle an async calculation chain in this situation is to do something like this (uses System.Threading):

```
function MyAdd( a,b : Int64): Int64;
begin
  Result := a + b;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Create(
    procedure
    var
      i: Int64;
    begin
      i := MyAdd(10,20);
      TThread.Queue(nil,  // Result is presented in the main thread.
        procedure
        begin
           mmo1.Lines.Add('on function call : ' + IntToStr(i));
           if (i <> 4) then
             mmo1.Lines.Add('on function call : <> 4'); 
        end);
    end).Start;
end;
```